# Bitmasking in Ruby: Get numbers which generated the bitmask

Tags: ruby, algorithm, bitmask

Currently I am storing a combination of a group of items as a single integer (bitmasked value) as in the example below:

### Example:

```
1 - Orange 
2 - Banana
4 - Cherry 
8 - Apple
```

And then if the user selects **Orange** (**1**) and **Apple** (**8**) then the sum of those is **9**.

And it is always and only when those two items are combined this value is **9**.

And you are able to recover the original two numbers which were used to generate this number.

Here is an example website which does the trick:
http://www.tfxsoft.com/playground/calc.php

### What I need:

I need an algoritm (preferrably in Ruby) which would take the sum (9) of those two bitmask values and return the values which it "contains" ( 1 and 4).

Comment: Annnndddd what have you tried so far?

Comment: This has been asked hundreds of times, usually not in Ruby I admit but it won't be fundamentally different..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
FRUIT = { 1 => 'Orange', 2 => 'Banana', 4 => 'Cherry', 8 => 'Apple' }

def mask_fruit(a, b) a | b end
def unmask_fruit(masked)
  FRUIT.select { |k, _| (masked | k) == masked } 
end

mask = mask_fruit 1, 8 # => 9
unmask_fruit mask # => {1=>"Orange", 8=>"Apple"}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to find position of bits. Here is simple but not optimal solution:

```
2.1.5 :033 > 9.to_s(2).reverse.chars.map.with_index { |b, i| b == "1" ? i + 1 : nil }.compact
 => [1, 4]
```

Comment: I think you meant to write: `9.to_s(2).reverse.chars.map.with_index { |b, i| b == '1' ? 2 ** i : nil }.compact # => [1, 8]`